# how does desire can kill your focus?

Tags: thought-experiment

I often experience my focus dropped when my desire increases. How does both related?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Unfortunately, I would interpret this question as more focused on psychology. I am not sure it is a proper question for this forum. Please take the time to read through the tour and help center information to help frame what questions should be included on the Philosophy.SE. They suggest limiting questions to the following; technical philosophical questions about metaphysics, aesthetics, logic or epistemology, The history of philosophy, Critical strategies for reading. Thank you. [LINK](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think desire and intensity are Proportional to each other. so focus should be gain and become more steady. it could only happen if you have multiple desire that are non-relative to each other and that leads to confusion.

And your confusion is the factor that dropping your focus. you need to prioritize your desire and than determined your objective so you can gain focus to achieve satisfaction to your desire.

good luck.

Comment: if you have multiple desire that are non-relative to each other and that leads to confusion.  Very good point.

Comment: @user3796318 thanks you can up-vote or accept if you like. i would like to know was it your case?